# Failed to compile: Module not found: Can't resolve '../../common/form' in 'src' components time'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Attempts to import the file `form.jsx` in the file`time.jsx`. I have an error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '../../common/form' in 'src /
>   components / time'

```
//src
    //common
        //form.jsx
    //components
        //calendar
            //time.jsx
```

**time.jsx**

```
import form from '../../common/form'
```

**Updated**

**form.jsx**

```
const form = () => {
  return (
    <div >

    </div>
  );
};


export default form;
```

Comment: @JosephD. `export default form;`

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you use for the export

Comment: Are you export default form in file `form.jsx` ?

Comment: Are you sure `time.jsx` is in a folder named calendar? I think the error says its directly in the components folder.

Comment: `'../../../form'`, how about this

Comment: `import form from '../../common/form.jsx';` how about this?

Comment: @DragonWhite you shouldnt have to specify .jsx it should work without explicititly specifying the file extension

Comment: try this import form from '../../common/form'

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

import { FormComponent } from '../../common/form';

//access it as  this error is because of tag form which is one of the keyword of jsx

```
//form.jsx
const FormComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div >

    </div>
  );
};


export default FormComponent;
```

Comment: yes it's a jsx keyword, but not a js keyword. And the import happens in Js

Comment: please do right tick as well if you are getting help.